# svg element missalignment in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, svg

I've to make an automation on SVG and I'm facing issues when trying to click on elements.

```
<svg width="500" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
<rect x="20" y="8" width="10" height="5" style="stroke: #303030; fill:tomato;"></rect>
```

Note that I'm in an iFrame and the best place to inspect the problem is here
http://jsfiddle.net/mnk/mzLkck0w/

Inspect element and rollover the `rect`.

Comment: So Chrome DevTools has some trouble with the iframe offset. What's it to you?